# lambda to prevent writing loops

Tags: python

Is there an easy pythonic way to write the following code without loops?

```
def get_ranges(request)-> List[DateTimeRange]:
    time_ranges = []
    for req in request:
        range = req[attr]
        time_ranges.append(DateTimeRange(
            datetime.fromtimestamp(range["start"]),
            datetime.fromtimestamp(range["end"])))
    return time_ranges
```

Here is what I tried:

```
time_ranges = [DateTimeRange(
                datetime.fromtimestamp(req[attr]["start"]),
                datetime.fromtimestamp(req[attr]["end"])) for req in requests ]
```

Comment: How about a list comprehension?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your code here has an error because `return` cannot be used outside a `def`.

Comment: That's fine. But you could extract function and map.

Comment: You can write this as a list comprehension. However, it will be overly complex and difficult to debug. The loop is much easier to read and understand what this code is doing.

Comment: You might consider making this a generator with `yield` rather than returning the entire list.

Comment: I tried writing a list comprehension but could not come up with one. Fairly new to python here

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, what's the advantage as writing it as a generator with yield?

Comment: @nebula186 The primary advantage of writing a generator is that the list objects are created as the caller iterates over them rather than storing them all in memory at once.

Comment: @nebula186 As for a list comprehension, you should show us what you tried, if you want to go that direction, and we can help from there. [Edit] your question to show your attempt and what the result was.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I updated the question. I also realized what I had done wrong. I was trying to index into attr incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a comprehension, since your loop fits the textbook format for one:

```
time_ranges = [DateTimeRange(
        datetime.fromtimestamp(req[attr]["start"]),
        datetime.fromtimestamp(req[attr]["end"]))
    for req in request]
```

This calls `__getitem__` on `req` twice, which may be undesirable, e.g. if it has any side effects beyond a simple dictionary or list lookup. To avoid that, you chain iterators:

```
time_ranges = [DateTimeRange(
        datetime.fromtimestamp(r["start"]),
        datetime.fromtimestamp(r["end"]))
    for r in (req[attr] for req in request)]
```

This is not the same as a nested `for` loop because of the explicit parentheses around the inner generator.

A similar formulation might use `operator.itemgetter` and `map`:

```
time_ranges = [DateTimeRange(
        datetime.fromtimestamp(r["start"]),
        datetime.fromtimestamp(r["end"]))
    for r in map(operator.itemgetter('attr'), request)]
```

Comment: You could also use intermediate variables: `ranges = (req[attr] for req in request)` and then `....for r in ranges`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. You could, but there's no need to make a new name except for legibility